# How to change root permission for uploading files in apache with php as backend language?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

```
<?php
    include_once 'database/dbconnect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){    

        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="uploads/";

        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);
        $sql="INSERT INTO upload(file,type,size)     VALUES('$file','$file_type','$file_size')";
        mysql_query($sql); 
    }
?>
```

```
<?php
    if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ){
        copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "uploads/" ) or 
            die( "Could not copy file!");
    }
    else{
        die("No file specified!");
    }
?>
```

When I try to upload any file using xampp, I'm facing an error which says

> Warning: copy(first.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-project/upload.php on line 4
>   Could not copy file!

I even tried to change the folder permission by

> sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-project/

But, nothing as changed.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to copy the file.

Comment: Do you have a folder called `uploads` under `new-project`? If not then you must first create it before the file can be moved to the new location. And why don't you use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`? `$_FILES['file']['name']` is only the original name of the file. The location of the temporary uploaded file can be found under `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: I have a folder named 'uploads' under new-project, aslo I have changed the permission of the folder too.

Comment: @user3620928 - See my last comment. You should use `tmp_name` instead of `name`.

Comment: Alright, I have changed the code for uploading files, but I'm unable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Configure The "php.ini" File**

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

`file_uploads = On`

Comment: Yeah, it's by default set to 'On'.

Comment: Check maximum upload limit also.

Answer (score 0):

Since `name` is the original name and **not** the path to the uploaded file you should use `tmp_name` instead:

```
// check so file is set and contains no error
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
    $destination = 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    // use move_uploaded_file() instead of copy()
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination);
}
else {
    die("No file specified!");
}
```

If `error` is not equal to 0 you can check what kind of error occured following this link: [`File upload errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)